# I am having trouble puting markers on a Map in R leafjet

Tags: r, r-leaflet

Here is my code:

```
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  setView(lng = -107.9917071, lat = 59.5, zoom = 3.5) %>%
  addPolygons(data = plant,
              color = "#660000",
              weight = 1,
              smoothFactor = 0.5) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = plant$lon, lat = plant$lat)
m
```

No matter what I try I get the following error message:

> Error in polygonData.default(data) :    Don't know how to get path
> data from object of class spec_tbl_df

My data frame from which my data comes is a simple 5 row by 3 columns of coordinates and the name of the place.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show your dataset? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Name      lat                lon
University  43.5339923 -80.2244647
University 49.8091536 -97.1330418
University 3.52682        -113.5244937
University 49.2519564 -123.2465285
University 45.5069177 -73.5791163

Comment: Can you put it in the question as `dput()` or `reprex()` like in the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had point data, not polygons.

```
library(leaflet)

plant <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("University","University",
                       "University","University","University"),
               lat = c(43.5339923, 49.8091536, 3.52682, 49.2519564, 45.5069177),
               lon = c(-80.2244647,-97.1330418,
                       -113.5244937,-123.2465285,-73.5791163)
)


leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  setView(lng = -107.9917071, lat = 59.5, zoom = 3.5) %>%
  # I removed the addPolygons(), you are adding points, not polygons
  addCircleMarkers(lng = plant$lon, lat = plant$lat)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! You are absolutely right! It took me hours to figure this out. My code now is:                 m <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  setView(lng = -94, lat = 52, zoom = 3.5) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(m, 
             lng = Canada$x2, 
             lat = Canada$x1, 
             radius = 1,  
             color = "#5F04B4",    
             weight = 10)
m